# Curly braces sizes mismatch in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

it happened after I installed Productivity Power Tools extension. It seemed not work with C++, so I deleted it. But after deletion, I noticed this "bug". I'm not even sure if it's extensions problem, but I really don't like it

[image]

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines

Comment: So the problem is that the closing brace is smaller than the opening one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably down to the [Shrink Empty Lines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.SyntacticLineCompression2022) extension which is part of the Productivity Power Tools suite. You can configure it under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Productivity Power Tools`